# Python re.sub changing parts of string into ascii

Tags: python, regex

```
test1 = "<test>222</test>blah blah blah"
newVal = "222"
mstring = "(<test>).*(</test>)"
newString = re.sub(mstring,rf"\1{newVal}\2",test1)
print(newString)
```

I am trying to find a particular value in my string and substitute with a different string using re.sub function. Seems like i am find the correct match and replace is working however python is converting parts of the string into its ascii equivalent value. Can you help me with the above code so that i produce the below output please

```
<test>222</test>blah blah blah
```

instead i am getting below result

```
R2</test>blah blah blah
```

Comment: Instead of `\1` and `\2` use `\\1` and `\\2`.

Comment: @MarkRansom sorry it is not working for me

Comment: @snakecharmerb I am using Python 3.7. I could try and upgrade to 3.8 and try again

Comment: @MarkRansom It can't work with your approach. The problem is given by ambiguity in replacement. See my answer for more details.

Comment: @RiccardoBucco my mistake, I didn't see the `r` at the start of the string.  I assumed the backslashes were being interpreted and not becoming part of the replacement string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
test1 = "<test>222</test>blah blah blah"
newVal = "111"
mstring = "(<test>).*(</test>)"
newString = re.sub(mstring, f'\g<1>{newVal}\g<2>', test1)`
print(newString) # <test>111</test>blah blah blah
```

Your approach would work with `newVal` being, for example, a letter:

```
newVal = "a"
re.sub(mstring, f'\1{newVal}\2', test1) # <test>a</test>blah blah blah
```

This weird behaviour is due to the fact that `\1{newVal}` (with `newVal=333`) would be interpreted as a reference to group 1333. The `\g<1>` syntax is equivalent to `\1`, but isn’t ambiguous in a replacement.

Comment: Thanks this is working for me

Comment: @Krishna I updated the answer with more details explaining why your approach is (sometimes) failing

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I started to learn python only recently but this looks like a very powerful functionality